# Apply two different formulas on four data frame columns

Tags: r, loops, case-when

I want to apply two different formulas on four columns of my dataframe df. I have done this manually, but since my original data frame has several columns, I want to be able to use loops or case when to do this faster.

Here's how sample dataframe df looks like:

```
A   B   C  D
20  100 4  1200
40  150 6  2300 
34  200 3  1230
32  225 9  1100
12  220 10 1000
```

Formula 1:

```
(x-max(x))/(max(x)-min(x))
```

Formula 2:

```
(min(x)-x)/(max(x)-min(x))
```

I'd like to apply formula 1 on columns B and D and formula 2 on columns A and C.

After applying the formula, I want to store the values in a different dataframe but with the same column names.

Here's what I did:

```
formula_1 <-function(x) {
  (((x - min(x)))/(max(x) - min(x))) 
}

    formula_2 <-function(x){(min(x)-x)/(max(x)-min(x))
}

Create an empty dataframe BI_score
BI_score$B <- formula_1(df$B)
BI_score$D <- formula_1 (df$D)
BI_score$A <- formula_2 (df$A)
BI_score$C <- formula_2 (df$C)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

As there are some `NA`s and `Inf` values and if we want to exclude them from calculation, we can handle it by updating the function as below and then apply the function to column as shown previously.

```
formula_1 <-function(x) {
   temp <- x[is.finite(x)]
   replace(x, is.finite(x), (((temp - min(temp)))/(max(temp) - min(temp))))
}

formula_2 <-function(x) {
   temp <- x[is.finite(x)]
   replace(x, is.finite(x), (min(temp)-temp)/(max(temp)-min(temp)))
}
```

---

The most straight forward approach would be to use `lapply` to apply the function separately on selected columns.

```
BI_score <- df
fm1_cols <- c("B", "D")
fm2_cols <- c("A", "C")
BI_score[fm1_cols] <- lapply(df[fm1_cols], formula_1)
BI_score[fm2_cols] <- lapply(df[fm2_cols], formula_2)


BI_score
#      A    B     C     D
#1 -0.29 0.00 -0.14 0.154
#2 -1.00 0.40 -0.43 1.000
#3 -0.79 0.80  0.00 0.177
#4 -0.71 1.00 -0.86 0.077
#5  0.00 0.96 -1.00 0.000
```

As mentioned by @Sotos, if you want to apply the function on alternate columns you could do

```
BI_score[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- lapply(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)], formula_1)
BI_score[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- lapply(df[c(FALSE, TRUE)], formula_2)
```

---

Just for fun, approach using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

bind_cols(df %>% select(fm1_cols) %>% mutate_all(formula_1), 
          df %>% select(fm2_cols) %>% mutate_all(formula_2))
```

Comment: Hey @Ronak, in my original data frame, there are a few NAs and `inf' that are breaking my code, sending down errors like : Error in max(x, na.rm = TRUE) - x : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator. How should I deal with these?

Comment: @ShreyaAgarwal I would suggest update the formula then? `min` and `max` both have `na.rm` argument. just replace `min(x)` with `min(x, na.rm = TRUE)` everywhere and same for `max`.

Comment: Sure, and for values like 'inf'?

Comment: For values which are `NA` and `Inf` what values do you want them to take in the new dataframe? Should they remain as it is?

Comment: Yes, they should remain as is.

Comment: @ShreyaAgarwal using `is.finite` would help you here. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Got it. Thanks much @Ronak.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to apply the two functions on alternating columns, then you can do it via logical indexing

```
cbind.data.frame(sapply(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)], formula_2),  
                 sapply(df[c(FALSE, TRUE)], formula_1))


#           A          C    B          D
#1 -0.2857143 -0.1428571 0.00 0.15384615
#2 -1.0000000 -0.4285714 0.40 1.00000000
#3 -0.7857143  0.0000000 0.80 0.17692308
#4 -0.7142857 -0.8571429 1.00 0.07692308
#5  0.0000000 -1.0000000 0.96 0.00000000
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `mutate_at` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate_at(vars(B, D), formula_1) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(A, C), formula_2)
```